# ImportError: html5lib not found after scraping data

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I was retrieving the player data sequentially from the ranking in this page: [https://www.baseball-reference.com/leaders/WAR_bat_career.shtml](https://stackoverflow.com).The program ran smoothly until[image: The screenshot of my terminal]it tried to get the data from the "15th" player in the rank (Mel Ott), the terminal signaled an `ImportError: html5lib not found, please install it`. After the error, I can't even retrieve data from the previous players that had being done. The thing that doesn't make sense to me is that if the library is indeed needed, then the error message should pop up at the first place, why did it occur after the 15th request?

This is the code for making sequential request:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

import requests
import pandas as pd

def counting_WAR(df):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        if type(df.iloc[i]["Age"]) is str:
            age = int(df.iloc[i]["Age"])
            if age <= 30:
                WAR = float(df.iloc[i]["WAR"])
                sum += WAR
            else: return sum

root_page = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/leaders/WAR_bat_career.shtml"
root_soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(root_page), features = 'lxml')
root_df = pd.read_html(requests.get('https://www.baseball-reference.com/leaders/WAR_bat_career.shtml').text.replace('<!--','').replace('-->',''), attrs={'id':'leader_standard_WAR_bat'})[0]

index = 0

for td in root_soup.find_all('td', csk = True):
    for a in td.find_all('a', href = True):
        player_page = ("http://www.baseball-reference.com" + a.get('href'))
        df = pd.read_html(requests.get(player_page).text.replace('<!--','').replace('-->',''), attrs={'id':'batting_value'})[0]
        df[(~df.Lg.isna()) & (df.Lg != 'Lg')]
        war_before_30 = "{:.2f}".format(counting_WAR(df))
        print("Player:", root_df["Player (yrs, age)"][index], "accumulates:", war_before_30, " WAR before 30")
        index += 1
```

I've tried to install the library the terminal asked for, but after that the program can't even locate the exact table I was looking for. This is the code that I used to retrieve the data:

```
df = pd.read_html(requests.get('https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/b/bondsba01.shtml').text.replace('<!--','').replace('-->',''), attrs={'id':'batting_value'})[0]
df[(~df.Lg.isna()) & (df.Lg != 'Lg')]
```

Any information and assistance will be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're requesting data too quickly. The site returns this message:

```html
<p>We apologize, but you have triggered rate limiting by our cloud service provider.</p>

<p>This could be for one of many reasons.
<ul class="bullets">
<li>You accessed more than thirty pages in less than a minute.</li>
<li>You have written a bot that accessed too many files too quickly.</li>
<li>Multiple people are accessing the site at the same time via your IP address.</li>
<li>You are an employee of ESPN.</li>
</ul>
```

**Web-scraping is about getting the job done, not launching a [DOS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack).**

Try this:

- reuse the connection by utilizing `request.Session()`
- add a human-like wait-time, for example, 2 to 5 seconds after each request
- use `"User-Agent"`
- use proxy and/or VPN to rotate your IP's

Some style notes:

- organize your imports; first built-ins, then installed; all arranged alphabetically
- don't use built-ins as variable names (`sum`)
- function names in python are `lowercase`
- try to keep line length to 80 - 120 characters
- don't mix `urllib` with `request`, use just one, preferably `requests`

For example:

```py
import time

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def counting_war(df):
    s = 0
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        if type(df.iloc[i]["Age"]) is str:
            age = int(df.iloc[i]["Age"])
            if age <= 30:
                s += float(df.iloc[i]["WAR"])
            else:
                return s


def wait_a_bit(wait_for: int = 5) -> None:
    time.sleep(wait_for)


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) "
                  "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/113.0.1774.35",
}
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(headers)

root_page = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/leaders/WAR_bat_career.shtml"
root_soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(root_page).text, "lxml")

source = (
    session
    .get('https://www.baseball-reference.com/leaders/WAR_bat_career.shtml')
    .text
    .replace('<!--', '')
    .replace('-->', '')
)

root_df = pd.read_html(
    source,
    attrs={'id': 'leader_standard_WAR_bat'},
    flavor="bs4",
)[0]

index = 0

for td in root_soup.find_all('td', csk=True):
    for a in td.find_all('a', href=True):
        player_page = ("https://www.baseball-reference.com" + a.get('href'))
        df = pd.read_html(
            session.get(player_page).text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', ''),
            attrs={'id': 'batting_value'},
        )[0]
        _ = df[(~df.Lg.isna()) & (df.Lg != 'Lg')]
        war_before_30 = "{:.2f}".format(counting_war(df))
        print(
            f'Player: {root_df["Player (yrs, age)"][index]} '
            f'accumulates: {war_before_30}  WAR before 30'
        )
        index += 1
        wait_a_bit()
```

Sample output:

```bash
Player: Barry Bonds (22) accumulates: 73.90  WAR before 30
Player: Babe Ruth+ (22) accumulates: 79.40  WAR before 30
Player: Willie Mays+ (23) accumulates: 76.80  WAR before 30
Player: Ty Cobb+ (24) accumulates: 97.90  WAR before 30
Player: Henry Aaron+ (23) accumulates: 80.50  WAR before 30
Player: Tris Speaker+ (22) accumulates: 77.60  WAR before 30
Player: Honus Wagner+ (21) accumulates: 47.60  WAR before 30
Player: Stan Musial+ (22) accumulates: 75.30  WAR before 30
Player: Rogers Hornsby+ (23) accumulates: 90.50  WAR before 30
Player: Eddie Collins+ (25) accumulates: 76.70  WAR before 30
Player: Ted Williams+ (19) accumulates: 71.60  WAR before 30
Player: Alex Rodriguez (22) accumulates: 85.10  WAR before 30
Player: Lou Gehrig+ (17) accumulates: 73.10  WAR before 30
Player: Rickey Henderson+ (25) accumulates: 70.10  WAR before 30
Player: Mel Ott+ (22) accumulates: 81.70  WAR before 30
Player: Mickey Mantle+ (18) accumulates: 90.80  WAR before 30
Player: Frank Robinson+ (21) accumulates: 71.60  WAR before 30

...
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice wait_a_bit function, that totally solve the problem, and thanks for additional help on the coding style, as you can see I am just a newbie in programming, so I appreciate that very much !

Answer (score 2):

Just in addition to @baduker - Love this:

> Web-scraping is about getting the job done, not launching a DOS
> attack.

Seems that there is an issue with the structure / HTML of this specific page:

> flavorstr, optional
> The parsing engine to use. ‘bs4’ and ‘html5lib’
> are synonymous with each other, they are both there for backwards
> compatibility. The default of None tries to use lxml to parse and if
> that fails it falls back on bs4 + html5lib.

So in first iterations `lxml` as standard of `bs4` is used, that is why there was no error message.

Also check if `html5lib` is installed in your environment, else install it:

```
pip install html5lib
```

Comment: Well, by sharing the code on SO this effectively becomes a DDOS attack. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately something true - Impatience and lack of depth can be bad companions, so I thought your comment was well placed and worth quoting.